# exim remote dovecot auth

Tags: authentication, dovecot, exim

I'm trying to setup dovecot authenticator in exim. I have followed this howto (http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/EximAndDovecotSASL) and it works perfect on local server. Now I need to use that method on another (remote) exim, so I cannot use sockets. I have added port listener for auth in dovecot, which works fine (I guess):

```
  inet_listener auth-client {                                                                                                                                                                                     
    name = remote                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    port = 55555                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    #ssl = yes                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }
```

But I have no idea how to set up that remote exim server. In the docs (http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_dovecot_authenticator.html) is mentioned only socket.

Does it mean that I cannot use port-based dovecot auth in exim? Thanks!

Comment: Try my solution for this. It is available by reference https://github.com/mrigoryan/exim-dovecot-auth

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to authenticate using a second dovecot running as a director.  This is the service you created the listener for.

Is the Exim second server a new MX?  I would consider making this the primary MX server and offload most of the incoming email traffic to it.  This should reduce the traffic the current server which can remain your submission server.  It would even be possible to remove the current server as an MX so that it has more capacity to handle MDA and Submission traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That idea already crossed my mind, but I thought that there is maybe a better solution than install dovecot to the second server as well.